# Modifying cookie subkeys in C#

Tags: c#, cookies

I can't for the life of me understand what I'm doing wrong here. I've searched high and low but everything I try doesn't seem to fix.

I'm trying to create a cookie that stores the first and last name of a user. If the user goes back and changes either the first or second name it should modify these subkeys in the userName cookie. This part doesn't seem to work though?

```
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("userName");
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Remove("userName");
                cookie.Values["firstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                cookie.Values["lastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                cookie.Values["firstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                cookie.Values["lastName"] = txtLastName.Text;

            }
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        }
        Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to `delete` cookies on the client browser is to `override` them, setting the `expires` value to a date in the past.

When you use this code:

```
Response.Cookies.Remove("userName");
```

you only delete the cookie on server, which Means it's not sent to the client. This Means the old cookie on the client is kept.

To delete the old cookie:

```
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("olduserName");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here `'oldusername'` contain the previous value of `'username'`.

**Edit**:

Another way is to name your cookie with a name that doesn't change, ever, then you can simply override it with the new value, when username changes.

**Edit2**:

I actually made the same mistake as you did, you should use:

```
Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

When using `Add` there can be *more than one* Cookie with the same name. This is most likely your problem (sorry, I did not see that before).

**Edit2**:

Just saw this line now:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx");
```

You are redirecting! Then the cookies are not set on the client.

Instead you should set the cookies in "~/Order.aspx".

Comment: Okay so just to be sure that code snippet replaces 

Response.Cookies.Remove(“userName”);

?

Is there any way to modify the subkey without deleting the cookie? I read I could update the subkey value and then add the cookie with the same name to override but that doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Your method will not Work, when you change username, since that is the name of the cookie.

Comment: Yeah that’s the part I’m getting tripped up in I think. The actual name of the cookie “userName” doesn’t change. But when I try to override the value of a subkey, say “firstName” and then do Response.Cookie.Add(“userName”); it doesn’t take the new value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can’t wait to try it when I get back in the office!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work either. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm not following how the redirect comes into this. I'm just learning, sorry. :(

Comment: @Caelisto This comment is for future reference purposes :-)  The "Response" is added to the response for the form that called the client-side method. If you redirect then the response for the form is never received by the client as they are redirected to what ever you are redirecting the client to.